# How to customize GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync and ResetPasswordAsync Methods of UserManager in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

The userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user); 
creates a long string and then ResetPasswordAsync(user,code,newPassword) takes user,token and password to validate. My requirement is to create a short code, say 5 to 10 (clear text) characters. Send the code in email. User can then insert the code and new password, and I validate the token. The problem is I do not know how to customize the above two methods to accomplish my results. There is not much help on the internet either. I tried different things like the following but I do not want my make any mistake and create security vulnerability.

```
 public class CustomPasswordTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser:class
{
    public CustomPasswordTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IOptions<PasswordResetTokenProviderOptions> options):
        base(dataProtectionProvider,options)
    {

    } 

}
public class PasswordResetTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public PasswordResetTokenProviderOptions()
    {    //  update the defaults
        Name = "CustomPasswordResetTokenPorvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the token length is a security feature? By reducing it this drastically, you are essentially degrading your security. That being said, the primary reason the token is this long is that it is actually encrypted information about the token request. So the password reset token for example contains the information that it is a password reset token for a specific user with an email. This allows the framework to validate the token _without_ having to store it separately. – If you want to use a shorter token, then you will have to *store* that token somewhere.